# .collect(Collectors.toList()) and Streams on Java Method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection (as hashmap) of Doctors, into a generic Hospital class.

```
Map<Integer, Doctor> doctors = new HashMap<Integer, Doctor>();
```

For each doctor I have some information such as in the class code (focus on the patients):

```
public class Doctor extends Person {
    private int id;
    private String specialization;
    private List<Person> patients = new LinkedList<Person>();
```

My purpose is to write this function which return busy doctors: doctors that has a number of patients larger than the average.

```
/**
 * returns the collection of doctors that has a number of patients larger than the average.
 */
Collection<Doctor> busyDoctors(){

    Collection<Doctor> doctorsWithManyPatients = 
            doctors.values().stream()
            .map( doctor -> doctor.getPatients() )
            .filter( patientsList -> { return patientsList.size() >= AvgPatientsPerDoctor; })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return null;
}
```

I want to use the streams as above to perform this operation. The problem is in `collect` method because at that point of usage `doctorsWithManyPatients` is of type `List<Collection<Person>>` and not `Collection<Doctor>`. How could I do that?

Assume that `AvgPatientsPerDoctor` is already defined somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't use `map` (`Doctor -> List<Person>`), it will be used in the `filter`:

```
doctors
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter( d -> d.getPatients().size() >= AvgPatientsPerDoctor)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For your case, `map( doctor -> doctor.getPatients() )` returns `Stream<List<Person>>` and you should convert it to `Stream<Doctor>` again after `filter`ing and before calling the `collect` method.

---

There is a different way that isn't the best one. Keep in mind that it changes the origin collection.

```
doctors.values().removeIf(d -> d.getPatients().size() < AvgPatientsPerDoctor);
```

Comment: You right. I understood. Thank you for the response. There is a way eventually to convert it to Stream<Doctor> as you mentioned? It is not really nedeed but just to know.

Comment: @GiuseppeCanto, if you have a constructor (or a method - name it as `creator`) which receives `List<Person>` and creates a new object of `Doctor` type

Comment: @GiuseppeCanto, then you could write `map(this::creator)` or `map(list -> this.creator(list))`

Comment: So cool. I did not know the .removeIf. Anyway there is an eventual possibility to use it executing a copy of the hashMap, without modify the doctors hashMap. But as you said the first is preferable: the cost on performing a copy is not comparable to the previous one. Thank you again for the other option. I learned one more thing.